# Idiomatic Ruby for breaking up method definition

Tags: ruby, idioms

I am trying to cut a line into pieces

```
define_method("start_#{event}!") do |user_or_enrollment, setting_name = nil, node_id = nil|
```

What is the conventional style for breaking up these long method call lines?

Answer (score 2):

The convention is you usually don't break up lines like that, you just deal with it. Not everything can be neatly expressed as short lines even if you strive to do that.

One approach to make the line shorter is to reduce the length of the variable names:

```
define_method("start_#{event}!") do |on, setting = nil, node = nil|
```

Or to use an options-style definition:

```
define_method("start_#{event}!") do |on, options = { }|
```

Where you call it like:

```
start_x!(user, setting: setting_name, node_id: node.id)
```

Comment: The first approach is better than passing hash, passing just a hash obscures arguments of the method. Parameters to a method are clear, self sufficient documentation of what is required to make the method behave.

Comment: @Зелёный Where self-documentation fails, documentation can take over.

Answer (score 1):

Block parameters can be split over multiple lines, the same way you can do it when defining method parameters:

```
define_method("start_#{event}!") do |
                                     user_or_enrollment,
                                     setting_name = nil,
                                     node_id = nil
                                    |
  # method body
end
```

Alternatively, you can indent differently depending on personal preference, e.g.

```
define_method("start_#{event}!") do |
  user_or_enrollment,
  setting_name = nil,
  node_id = nil
|
  # method body
end
```

How exactly you format this is up to you. Various style guide recommend different things in that case. However, they usually all agree that it is desirable to keep the number of parameters small and to try to avoid splitting argument or parameter lists over multiple lines if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily based on opinion. I would go with:

```
define_method(
  "start_#{event}!"
) do |user_or_enrollment, setting_name = nil, node_id = nil|
```